# Why is vector<Data*>::iterator valid and vector<Data*>*::iterator not?

Tags: c++, vector

I have these three related class members:

```
vector<Frame*>* poolFrames;
vector<Frame*>*::iterator frameIterator;
vector<vector<Frame*>::iterator>* poolFrameIterators;
```

When I compile, gcc tells me

> error: invalid use of ‘::’
>   error: expected ‘;’ before ‘frameIterator’

In reference to the middle line, where I define frameIterators. It goes away when I loose the pointer to the vector and make it a vector::iterator. However, I want them to be pointers. Is there a special way to define the data type that I want, or do I need to use vector::iterator and then dereference?

Comment: It's not valid because it doesn't make any sense (according to the C++ ISO standard). I can't even figure out what it is you want...
Keep in mind that storing vector-iterators is not the best idea because vector-iterators will get invalid pretty easily.

Comment: I know what I am doing, know that it could be instable, and have precautions to avoid issues it. I want to iterate over a vector of Frame*, however the vector needs to be a pointer.

Comment: There is your confusion: You don't seem to distinguish between pointer and pointee. Just loose the 2nd asterik in the 2nd line and you're fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see what you were trying to do. You've defined `poolFrames` as a pointer to a vector. Then you want to define `frameIterator` as an iterator for `poolFrames`. Since `poolFrames` is a pointer, you think you need a special pointer-to-vector iterator, but you're mistaken.

A vector iterator is a vector iterator is a vector iterator, no matter how you managed to refer to the vector in the first place. You need `frameIterator` to be a simple iterator:

```
vector<Data*>::iterator frameIterator;
```

To assign a value to that variable, you'll need to dereference your vector pointer, like this:

```
frameIterator = poolFrames->begin();
```

If `poolFrames` were a vector instead of a pointer to a vector, you'd use the dot operator instead: `poolFrames.begin()`.

Comment: Thank you, you actually understood what I was trying to do. That answers it all for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a pointer to an iterator do it this way round:

```
vector<Frame*>::iterator*
```

The asterisk always follows the type that is pointed to. The way you have it is pretty much like writing `vector*<Frame*>::iterator`, it just has the asterisk in the wrong place.

Comment: I don't think that's true. My first declaration, 'vector<Frame*>*' compiles fine while 'vector*<Frame*>' does not.

Comment: It is true.  In your first declaration the type pointed to is `vector<Frame*>`, and following with an asterisk gives `vector<Frame*>*`.  In the second declaration, I *think* you want the type pointed to to be `vector<Frame*>::iterator`, in which case following with an asterisk gives `vector<Frame*>::iterator*`.  If that's not enough I think you should clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

What data type do you actually want?

`vector<Frame*>* poolFrames;` is a pointer to a vector of Frame pointers. Do you actually just want a vector of Frame pointers?

In that context, the error makes sense. A `vector<Frame*>` has iterators. A pointer to such a thing does not have iterators.

Comment: so I need to dereference every time I want to get a pointer out of an iterator, correct?

Answer (score 0):

The type of vector* is a pointer, which has no iterators.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<Frame*>*
```

Is a type expression but it does not have a member `iterator`
It's kind of like using `.` on a pointer.